# Year round pollen producers to sustain miniature pirate bugs for pest control

Tags: flowers, pest-control, insects

I would like to use miniature pirate bugs to control thrips and other potential pests in my greenhouse, they seem quite effective but I do not want the population to die off too much when there are not many pests left for them to eat.

They can sustain themselves on pollen so what would be some good year-round small flowering plants that could keep them going? High pollen production would mean I wouldn't need as many but being pretty or edible would be other advantages.

Comment: Without knowing your region, continent, climate, etc. it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Oh gosh of course, I'm in New Zealand so fairly cold in winter but I will use heaters to prevent frosts.

Comment: That climate it is outside my knowledge. You can check botanical gardens for some inspirations. Usually they try to have few flowers at every period. Additionally big garden shops (outside cities) have greenhouses so check what flowers they have in winter. Probably it is also good to build some shelter for the bugs, so that they can pass the winter (maybe just as eggs) and they can start populating your garden in spring.